# Sobolev Spaces separable

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

How do I demonstrate that the Sobolev spaces $W^{1,\infty}$ is not separable? PS: I know that space $L^{1,\infty}$ is not separable but was unable to use this information.

Comment: @Frank no, $W^{1,\infty}$ embeds into $L^\infty$, not the other way round.

Comment: @Thomas, yes sorry, don't know what I was thinking!

Comment: It is better to know why, or how to prove, that $L^\infty$ is not separable, than to just know that it is not. The same ideas work for both. Consider indicator functions of (arbitrary) unions of intervals (or unions of some of the intervals $[n,n+1]$).